# How do I sort the authors of a repository by the number of contributions using git?

Tags: command-line, git

The name of an author is exactly the one given by the "Author" line of a commit. When I list the authors, their names must be followed by the number of commits they have.

Answer (score 7):

Run this to get the list of authors ordered by number of commits:

`git shortlog -sn`

[Example output is available here.](https://gist.github.com/60cce2667cd56b799d34d)

Comment: And how do I append the number of contributions after the name of each author?

Comment: @johnny https://gist.github.com/60cce2667cd56b799d34d - it doesn't append, it does however prepend.

Comment: @jrg please fix the link. it is broken